# How to access the instance variable value from the diffrrent class in C#

Tags: c#, oop, instance

Creating a class with property a1

```
class A
{
    public int a1 { get; set; }
}
```

Creating object for Class A in B and assigning value to it

```
class B
{
    A a=new A();
    a.a1=45;
}
```

How to get the the assigned value in different class.

```
class C
{
    //How to access the  45  value from the class B instance variable here 
    //without using static keyword.
}
```

Comment: You need to expose B.a either through a getter property or a method unless you want to resort to reflection.

Comment: Your `B` class won't compile.

Comment: Can you explain more

Comment: This is pretty basic object-oriented stuff. You need to pick up an introductory book.

Answer (score 0):

you could try

```
class A
{
    public int a1 { get; set; }
}

class B
{
    public A a = new A();
    public B()
    {
        a.a1 = 45; //you need to put that in a method..
    }
}

class C
{
    B b = new B();   // instance of B in C
    int aValue = b.a.a1;  // access b's instance of A
}
```

better solution:

```
class A
{
    public int a1 { get; set; }
}

class B
{
    A a = new A();

    public int A_Value
    {
        get { return a.a1; }
        set { a.a1 = value; }
    }
}

class C
{
    B b = new B();   // instance of B in C
    public C()
    {
        b.A_Value = 45;
    }
}
```

Comment: While this could technically work, your `B` class is of poor design, generally speaking. Your comment about needing to put the `a1` assignment in a variable is also incorrect. I wouldn't have downvoted except for that misleading comment. You could easily just write it as `class B { public A a = new A { a1 = 45 };`, but again, public fields in a class are generally considered a no-no and should instead be exposed through a getter property or a method.

Comment: You're right. I've edited my answer mentioning your comment :)

Comment: Yup, but now you've changed it so `C` dictates the value. The OP wants to know how to retrieve the value from `C` when it's set in `B`.

Answer (score 0):

Accept either an A or B as a parameter either in the method or constructor. In the case below, A and B are interchangeable.

```
public class C
{
    A _a;
    public C(A a)
    {
        _a = a;
    }

    void Do() // Using constructor parameter.
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_a.a1); // Should print 45, so long as your other code has already ran.
    }

    void Do(B b) // Using method parameter.
    {
        Console.WriteLine(b.A.a1); // will write 45
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With respect, these answers just seem to be muddying the water. At risk of feeding a troll here, because it appears this question has no practical application, I'll submit my suggestion. Aside from some basic conventions, I'd added public constructors for each class, applied a public getter for the instance of A stored in B, and then provided a method on C that returns the "A1" property from the instance of A within the instance of B. Having written that last sentence punctuates how convoluted this task has been.

```
public class A
{
    public A() { }

    public int A1 { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public B()
    {
        this._a = new A() { A1 = 42 };
    }

    private A _a;

    public A A
    {
        get { return _a; }
    }
}

public class C
{
    public C() { }

    public int GetA1FromA()
    {
        return new B().A.A1;
    }
}
```